# EDO - Power Series Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well, here I have my equation:
$$
y''-x^2y = 0
$$
Assuming
$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n$
is a solution, then we could write (jumping some few steps)
$$2C_2+6C_3 x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty[(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}x^k+C_{K-2}x^k] = 0$$
What would give us
$C_2 = 0$, $C_3=0$ by comparison and
$$C_{k+2}=-\frac{C_{k-2}}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$
And with this forth equation we reach
$$y(x)=C_0+C_1x-\frac{C_0}{12}x^4-\frac{C_1}{20}x^5-\frac{C_0}{672}x^8+...$$
But as you can see everything is depending on $C_0$ and $C_1$ which are constants of my equation, but I have a question:
in [Airy's Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) ($y''-xy=0$) there is two solutions. One you get by saying $C_0=0$ and $C_1=1$ and another saying $C_0=1$ and $C_1=0$, could I do the same in this one? Why define it equal 1 and 0 in Airy's Equation?
I hope this was enough for understanding, thanks for the help anticipatedly.

Comment: You can define the "funamental solutions" as any (lineary independent) combinations of $C_0 f_0(x) + C_1 f_1(x)$. For example $f_0(x) - f_1(x)$ ($C_0=-C_1 = 1$) and $f_0(x) + f_1(x)$ ($C_0=C_1=1$) would be a valid choice.

Comment: @Winther but in Airy's Equation he gets two solutions, if I had three unknown constants I would have three solutions and the final solution would be the sum of them as shown in the link for Airy's Equation or just two separeted solutions as in a youtube video I watched?

Comment: You are dealing with a linear second order differential equation. Such an equation is always fully specified by providing two numbers (say $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$) so there are only two fundamental solutions here. If you had a third order ODE like $y''' = xy$ then you would have had three solutions. You are free to make the same choice $(C_0,C_1) = (1,0)$ for the first and $(0,1)$ for the second just as for the Airy equation. The only thing that is important is that you can construct the most general solution (as in your $y(x)  = \ldots$) as a linear combination of your two fundamental solutions.

Comment: You are awesome @Winther , thanks for the help!

Comment: Try a look at *Weber Differential Equations*.